# Include Swing when compiling with javac

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

I compile and jar the source just fine, but when I run it, it complains:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.swing.JPanel`

I guess I have to include the Swing library when compiling, but how do I do that?

I included every rt.jar on my system:

```
javac -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.4/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/me/equinox.jar *java
```

Still compiles fine, still crashes when run.

Comment: If it compiles, but doesn't run, we need to know how you are running the app (not how you are compiling it).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/). It's an old project that attempted to produce a Java implementation as pure open source.

They got about halfway, but the implementation is far from perfect. These days, it's better to avoid it entirely and instead use [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) (or the [Oracle/Sun JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), if open source is not a requirement).

On Ubuntu you can use [`update-java-alternatives`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) to configure your system to a different Java implementation:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-openjdk
```

By the way, you **never** need to specify `rt.jar` explicitly on your classpath, as it's always available automatically. Also, using *multiple* `rt.jar` from *different* JVMs is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: +1 - I wouldn't use GCJ for anything unless there were "political reasons" to do so ... and deadlines didn't matter.

Comment: @Stephen C: gcj and gnu classpath served their purpose by building first "clean" versions of IcedTea/OpenJDK. I think these projects deserve some recognition :)

Comment: @tulskiy: they sure did and they sure do. That doesn't change the fact that I wouldn't use them as a productive Java environment.

Comment: @tulskly - also, we should note the role that the gcj and gnu classpath work had in prodding Sun into create OpenJDK.  However, what @Joachim said is also true.  They are technically inferior, and using them adds significant risks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code, the compilation worked fine.
It is weird that you are missing this particular class as it is part of the standard library. In most Java distributions, this is in rt.jar

Answer (score 0):

What is your current path to the JDK (in $PATH or %PATH%)?  What is your whole path?  What is your current CLASSPATH environment variable?  Your problem is runtime environment related.  You should not add rt.jar to your classpath.  If you have a proper JVM install, then java doesn't need the location to rt.jar and tools.jar.  I suspect that you have pathing issues to the JVM.

Also, what is the command line you are using to run the program?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include rt.jar, it is included by the default classloader of the java vm.

You need to find out which version of java is the default one:

```
java --version
```

if you're running ubuntu, it will most probably be openjdk java, which is fine. If it's gcj, try to run it with openjdk or sun-jdk.

Also, show exactly how you run the jar.

Comment: ad `rt.jar`: "it is included in your JRE/JDK" is more correct.

Comment: `readlink -f $(which java)` may also help to find out exactly which java binary you are using.